# C++ Mystic structure assignment with int truncated

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I have the following code (c++11) :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Icons
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint8_t a  : 1;
            uint8_t b  : 1;
            uint8_t c  : 1;
            uint8_t : 5;
        };
        uint8_t Data;
    } Bla;

    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint8_t d  : 1;
            uint8_t e  : 1;
            uint8_t : 6;
        };
        uint8_t Data;
    } Foo;

    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint8_t f   : 1;
            uint8_t g   : 1;
            uint8_t h   : 1;
            uint8_t i   : 1;
            uint8_t : 4;
        };
        uint8_t Data;
    } Bar;
}TypeStruct;

int main()
{

    static constexpr TypeStruct NONE    = {0x00,0,0}; 
    static constexpr TypeStruct A =       {0x01,0,0};    
    static constexpr TypeStruct B   =     {0x02,0,0};     
    static constexpr TypeStruct C     =   {0x04,0,0};    

   return 0;
}
```

Compiling and working fine with IAR, but with GCC in pedantic, I get the following error which troubles me for a few days now...

```
$g++ -std=c++11 -o main *.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:50:52: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
     static constexpr TypeStruct B   =     {0x02,0,0};
                                                    ^
main.cpp:51:52: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
     static constexpr TypeStruct C     =   {0x04,0,0};
                                                    ^
```

I don't understand why!
Maybe something to do with union but I tried different writings with no match:
 {1,0,0} or {{1},{0},{0}}, or {{1,0,0}}
The problem is that i need to use something like "A" in a specialisation, and this can't be changed, let's say:

```
MyClass:MyMotherClass(TypeStruct A);
```

Thanks

---

EDIT:
Solution chosen was using:

```
static constexpr TypeStruct A   =   {{1,0,0},{0,0},{0,0,0,0}};     
static constexpr TypeStruct B   =   {{0,1,0},{0,0},{0,0,0,0}};      
static constexpr TypeStruct C   =   {{0,0,1},{0,0},{0,0,0,0}};  
etc...
```

However with this solution which compiles like a charm with IAR and GCC, I get the following PC lint message, Priority: High, Category: 4397.

```
 "pc lint constexpr variable 'A' must be initialized by a constant expression"
 "pc lint constexpr variable 'B' must be initialized by a constant expression"
 "pc lint constexpr variable 'C' must be initialized by a constant expression"
```

Comment: Field `uint8_t a  : 1;` is too short for values `2` or greater.

Comment: yes but i'm writing in the Bla.Data, ain't I? I don't want to write in Bla.a but in Bla.Data. What is the right writing?

Comment: No you're not. You would be if `Data` was the first member of each union. It is not.

Comment: Note that the compiler is allowed to change the order of the members of a bit-field.  Also note that C++ does not allow type-punning with unions, if you write to a member of a union you *must* read only from that same member.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ie. No writing to `Data` and reading from the members of the struct. Look into something like this: https://blog.codef00.com/2014/12/06/portable-bitfields-using-c11

Comment: What is message 4397?  It used to be that messages in the 300-399 range (mod 1000) were "fatal errors", which would be bizarre here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to get the code compiling with IAR and GCC and to avoid PC-lint error #4397:

`static const` should be used instead of `static constexpr`

```
static const TypeStruct A   =   {{1,0,0},{0,0},{0,0,0,0}};     
static const TypeStruct B   =   {{0,1,0},{0,0},{0,0,0,0}};      
static const TypeStruct C   =   {{0,0,1},{0,0},{0,0,0,0}};      
static const TypeStruct D   =   {{0,0,1},{1,0},{0,0,0,0}}; 
etc...
```

Answer (score 3):

The initializations are being applied to the bitfield struct because it is declared first in the union.  (Put the uint8_t Data member first and see the warning go away).  As a result 0x02 and 0x04 are too large for the first member (uint8_t a).

You could fix this by explicitly specifying the bitfield initializations, e.g.

```
static constexpr TypeStruct B   =   {{0,1},0,0};     
static constexpr TypeStruct C   =   {{0,0,1},0,0};
```

Note that, in general, there is no guarantee that bitfields will correspond to bit positions in bytes (or other integer types) - it's up to the compiler. So direct initializations of bitfield structs with byte values like 0x02 and 0x04 were a poor idea to begin with.

Comment: With this solution, it works with IAR and GCC, but i have a PC lint warning (High level): "pc lint constexpr variable 'B' must be initialized by a constant expression"

Comment: Sorry, don't know much about PC lint.  It may be complaining that _all_ fields in the bitfield struct haven't been explicitly initialized, i.e. that the padding fields need initializing zeros too.  B = {{0,1,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0}}. That's just a guess, btw.